# Alguém experiente que entenda bem manipulação de Strings, que possa ajudar nesse erro

Tags: array, c++, string, vector

Bom dia, estou apresentando um problema que não faço ideia o motivo, já tentei perguntar para outras pessoas, nenhuma descobriu o real motivo do erro e como repara-lo. Bom meu professor, pediu para implementar um sistema com o qual abre um arquivo txt que contem palavras e essas palavras devem ser armazenadas em uma árvore trie. A implementação dessa árvore com um teste está disponível em: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/trie-insert-and-search/

Dessa forma, a implementação dessa arvore está muito próxima do que precisa ser feito, uma vez que através de um array de string são inseridas as palavras na árvore. Abaixo a função "main" da implementação que forneci do link, a saída desse programa está tudo correto, indicando que não há a palavra "these" e há a palavra "the"

[[image: Imagem da implementação da internet, tudo funciona corretamente[1]]

Então básicamente eu adaptei o código fazendo a leitura do arquivo txt e não funcionou, acredito que o problema possa ter relação com o método insert. Fiz um teste também, printando todas as palavras do arquivo e felizmente funcionou, ou seja o problema está só em inserir as palavras

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não faz sentido todas as palavras estarem certas conforme a saída. E na hora de dizer se essa palavra existe ou não na árvore não funcionar, usei a mesma implementação que estava funcionando corretamente. Agradeço muito se alguem souber oque fiz de errado

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/112052

Comment: Favor [edit] e postar o código como texto. Depois selecione e clique no botão `{}` do editor para formatar.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente recomendo sempre postar o próprio código e não a imagem, facilita para tentarmos simular e ajudar na solução. Tentei reproduzir seu código e percebi que o erro está na expressão regular do regex. Na verdade a expressão que você definiu nem conseguiu rodar no meu teste (estou usando visual studio 2017, não sei se tem problema pelo ambiente). De qualquer forma consegui executar da maneira esperada usando o código abaixo, onde precisei alterar a expressão regular do regex.

```
int main()
{
    // Input keys (use only 'a' through 'z' 
    // and lower case) 
    string subject = "the a there answer any by bye their";

    struct TrieNode *root = getNode();

    // Construct trie 
    regex re = regex("\\w+");
    sregex_iterator next(subject.begin(), subject.end(), re);
    sregex_iterator end;
    int i = 0;

    while (next != end) {

        smatch match = *next;
        string palavra = match.str();
        replace(palavra.begin(), palavra.end(), '[', '\0');
        replace(palavra.begin(), palavra.end(), ']', '\0');

        cout << palavra << " " << i << endl;
        insert(root, palavra);
        next++;
        i++;
    }

    // Search for different keys 
    search(root, "the") ? cout << "Yes\n" :
        cout << "No\n";
    search(root, "these") ? cout << "Yes\n" :
        cout << "No\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Segue imagem do output:

[image: Output]